# Creating RDS MySql Read Replica from aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am creating a python script to create read replica. Here is the code i wrote.

```
 import boto3
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     client= boto3.client('rds')
     client.create_db_instance_read_replica(
     DBInstanceIdentifier='database-replica',
     SourceDBInstanceIdentifier='database-1',
     )
```

I am getting this error:

```
errorMessage": "Connect timeout on endpoint URL: \"https://rds.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/\""
```

I have configured all the IAM roles that i think i needed. Can any one have experience with similar problem.

Comment: It seems like you've put your Lamba function in a Subnet with no Internet Access.

Comment: Its not the case, All subnets have a route connected to internet gateway

Comment: Can you confirm that you attached your lambda with Private Subnets. When it comes to Internet Access, Lambda Requires the NAT Gateway to access Internt.

Comment: To access private Amazon VPC resources, such as a Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) DB instance associate your Lambda function in an Amazon VPC with one or more private subnets. Ref - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: no, the subnets are public subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access private Amazon VPC resources, such as a Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) DB instance or Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance, associate your Lambda function in an Amazon VPC with one or more private subnets.

To grant internet access to your function, its associated VPC must have a NAT gateway (or NAT instance) in a public subnet.

And ensure your RDS Security Group has a self-reference. [means attaching its own Security Group to itself]

[Ref](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)